# I have a list of buttons and I can't access them

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a list of buttons and I am trying to get all of them into an array to click one by one.

```
<ul> 
<li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data selected"><button class="ut-image-button-control btnAction"></button></li>
<li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"><button class="ut-image-button-control btnAction"></button></li>
<li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"><button class="ut-image-button-control btnAction"></button></li>
</ul>
```

I tried something like this.

```
clicks = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ut-image-button-control'))
for c in clicks:
    c.click()
```

But it didn't work. Can someone help me with a new code (a new find_element_by....)or something?

UPDATE:

[image]

This is the list I want to click on each button.

Comment: I will check right now

Answer (score 1):

To click on each button.Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()
and following css selector.

```
clicks=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.ut-image-button-control.btnAction")))
for c in clicks:
    c.click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` this method will get all the buttons from the page?

Comment: Yes,You will get all buttons from the page.

Comment: Now I get the next error without a message: `TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: I've put on the method what you said, and after that, I tried to use it when I click on a Tkinter button

Comment: can you try this css selector : `li.istFUTItem.has-auction-data>button.ut-image-button-control.btnAction`

Comment: The same error, I have edited my question. Can you have a look, maybe you will have an idea.

Comment: @PaulVio : The element may be inside an iframe can you share me the url?

Comment: Hmm I don't know how. Maybe I can share with you the whole unordered list?

Comment: Because you can see the inspector element only if you are logged in